# python return statement with strings and functions

Tags: python, string, function, return, multiple-return-values

```
def intron_comparison(retained_introns_file, non_retained_introns_file):
    with open(retained_introns_file, 'r') as r, open(non_retained_introns_file, 'r') as nr:
        r_gc = avg_gc(r)
        nr_gc = avg_gc(nr)
        r_avglen = intlength(r)
        nr_avglen = intlength(nr)
        r_percdiv = intdiv(r)
        nr_percdiv = intdiv(nr)
    return ('The GC content for non retained introns is ' + nr_gc + '\n' +
        'The GC content for retained introns is ' + r_gc + '\n' +
        'The average length of non retained introns is ' + nr_avglen + '\n' +
        'The average length of retained introns is ' + r_avglen + '\n' +
        'The percent of non retained introns divisible by 3 is ' + nr_percdiv + '\n' +
        'The percent of retained introns divisible by 3 is ' + r_percdiv + '.')
```

Above is a function I've written that pulls together 3 other functions and compares 2 files across them. I'd like the return statement to denote a descriptor before each value, as you can see, but I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

regarding that last line. What am I missing?

EDIT: The code works wonderfully, I'm just having problems with that return statement - I assume it's some small thing I am missing? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: One of those variables that you try to concatenate with strings is `None`. Strings can only be concatenated with other strings. My psychic debugging tells me that those functions you're calling are just printing their values rather than returning string representations of their calculated values.

Comment: One of your 6 functions is returning `None`. Better wrap those variables in `str()` when concatenating with strings.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Now the hunt is on for those None values.... :)

Answer (score 0):

For big string like what you have do a few things.

First use """ """ instead of trying to build it the way you are.

Second use either % style or format to interpolate the values into strings. The newer python recommendation is to use format.

```
return """The GC content for non retained introns is {nr_gc}
The GC content for retained introns is {r_gc}
The average length of non retained introns is {nr_avglen}
The average length of retained introns is {r_avglen}
The percent of non retained introns divisible by 3 is {nr_percdiv}
The percent of retained introns divisible by 3 is {r_percdiv}.
""".format(r_gc = avg_gc(r),
           nr_gc = avg_gc(nr),
           r_avglen = intlength(r),
           nr_avglen = intlength(nr),
           r_percdiv = intdiv(r)
           nr_percdiv = intdiv(nr))
```

Comment: This will eliminate the error, but it'll still be printing `None` for affected values.

Comment: The question wasn't how to get rid of the None's it was how to display the results. In the question he specifically said the results of the functions were correct

Comment: And, as I said, we don't know if the functions are _supposed_ to return `None`, which is what they'll do if they have previously been printing their results and not returning anything.